# Forcing json to dump a json object even when list is empty

Tags: python, json

I have a list, which may be empty or non-empty.

I want to create a new file which contains that list in a format that is human-readable and easy for my next script to parse.  In the case where the list is non-empty, this works fine and my next script reads in the json file.  But when the list is empty, I get "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded."  This makes sense, because when I open the file, there is indeed no content and thus no JSON object.

I'm OK with the fact that some lists are empty.  So, either I want to write an empty JSON object or I want my reader script to be OK with not finding a JSON object.

Here's the relevant code:

**Writer Script**

```
favColor = []   OR   favColor = ['blue']   OR favColor = ['blue', 'green']
fileName = 'favoriteColor.json'
outFile = open(fileName, 'w')
json.dump(outFile, favColor)
outFile.close()
```

**Reader Script**

```
fileName = 'favoriteColor.json'
inFile = open(fileName, 'r')
colors = json.load(inFile)
inFile.close()
```

Any help or suggestions much appreciated.  If I need to provide more rationale for why I'm doing this, I can provide that as well, just thought I'd start off with minimum necessary to understand the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Dumping an empty list as JSON to a file should cause the file to contain `[]`, not be empty.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Modify your reader script to this:

```
with open('favoriteColor.json') as inFile:
    try: 
         colors = json.load(inFile)
    except ValueError: 
         colors = []
```

This attempts to load the file as a json. If it fails due to a value error, we know that this is because the json is empty. Therefore we can just assign colors to an empty list. It is also preferable to use the "with" construct to load files since it closes them automatically.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, and good explanation of why the "with open() as ..." is preferred.  I have heard people say that it's preferred before, but without the reason it never got me to change.

Comment: I've just been debugging a problem caused by somebody who used this solution. The problem is that the file had become genuinely corrupt, but we just ignored it and returned an empty dict. This is a bad solution. You should test explicitly for an empty file.

Comment: @MatthewBooth You're right, this solution doesn't cover the case where the file is corrupted. Sorry for the trouble caused at your company. :P

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't take the approach you're trying. I would instead `json.dump` a dictionary, eg:

```
d = {'var1': '123', 'var2': [1, 2, 3]}
json.dump(d, fileout)
```

Then use `dict.get` to default it to a suitable value:

```
json_dict = json.load(filein)
favColor = json_dict.get('favColor', [])
```

Then you still have compulsory values that can except if not present using `[]` notation.

Puts the logic of missing values in your code instead of the json parsers...

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the name of the variable in your json file:

```
json.dump({'favorite-color': favColor}, outFile)
outFile.close()
```

And handle the case of an empty list when reading the json file:

```
data = json.load(inFile)

if len(data['favorite-color']) == 0:
    ...
```

Note that you must provide the object that you want to save and then the file-like object to `json.dump`.